# File not found error on import with Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode7, header-files, importerror

I am getting an error when trying to import a header file, that is part of a 3rd party framework.

While `#import "fileName.h"` brings up an error,  `@class fileName;` does not raise issues. In fact, I can navigate to the header from the class statement. Unfortunately, having @class fileName; doest not fit to the requirement of my code, and an import is needed for my purposes.

So far, I have tried to manually copy the specific folder that contains the file into the project - it did not solve the issue. Also, tried to add the path to Framework search paths in build settings, as well in user header search path. 
The following solution found on a different thread - `#import <Framework/fileName.h>` also did not work.

It goes without saying, that the exact project builds perfectly with Xcode 6.

Comment: Using `#import <Framework/fileName.h>` is the correct syntax.

Comment: I have tried it and it did not work.. the regular #import "fileName.h" works for older versions of Xcode.

Comment: I expect that only works if you've played with the *Header Search Paths*, which you should not need to do.

Comment: What do you mean, played with? I have kept it the same as it is with the previous versions of xcode. also, could you explain what is different between these two versions, and why it happens?

Comment: "Played with" means "changed so that `#import` statement will work".  I've no idea why it's happening.